# Does hibernate (and JPA) treat @OneToOne and @ManyToOne differently?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've always used the `@OneToOne` and `@ManyToOne` relations based on the logic behind the relation - if it is only one entity on each end, then it's one-to-one. If the entity on the other side may have more than one corresponding entities on this side, then it's many-to-one. i.e. a student has exactly one student book, and each student book belongs to exactly one student (one-to-one)

However, I just saw a couple of `@OneToOne` annotation in our codebase that are not actually one-to-one. Somehow, this has worked for quite some time, and I wonder whether hibernate treats these annotations differently?

Probably it won't allow a `@OneToMany` mapping on the other side, if there's `@OneToOne` on an entity, but apart from that?

Comment: Did you look at DB constraints used in both cases? Perhaps there is a unique in case of `@OneToOne` but not in case of `@OneToMany`?

Comment: I just checked - no unique constraints are created. The thing is - it works, which is odd :)

Comment: in fact, on one occasion it used to generate a unique constraint indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below link for a comprehensive explanation about supported mapping associations available in hibernate.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html

Comment: sorry, that doesn't work as an answer. It is a comment at best. I have checked the documentation and it doesn't specifically mention how the engine differentiates the mapping types. And the link is about a rather old version of hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Hibernate in particular works, but EclipseLink as a JPA provider does not differentiate the two.  And most applications do not either; technically a OneToOne should have a unique constraint on the foreign key, but I've never seen one used, and many applications use it and allow the target to be reused.

The JPA spec doesn't place any additional restrictions on ManyToOne behavior, so I would not rely on it in any provider.  I've only ever used ManyToOne as back pointers to OneToMany relationships - if there isn't a OneToMany, I just use OneToOne.